# changing value of input does not work in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change input value using its id in jquery but it does not work and neither return any message of error in the console.

I also have done some console.log in order to verify if the data are not empty and they are not

Below is my script

```
   $('.changer_etat').click(function(){
        var id_etat = $(this).closest('tr').find('span.id_etat').text();
        var date_depart = $(this).closest('tr').find('span.date_depart').text();
        var date_fin = $(this).closest('tr').find('span.date_fin').text();
        var etat_programme = $(this).closest('tr').find('span.etat_programme').text();
        $('#date_depart').val(date_depart);
        console.log(date_fin);
        console.log(id_etat);
        console.log(etat_programme);
    });
```

I've tried many thing. Like

```
$('#date_depart').attr('value',date_depart)
```

but this not work, I also tried with `append` method with no success

All searches made on that website or on google does not permitted me to find an issue.

Edit :

Below is the php part with all rows and there class

```
` <?php while ($historique = mysql_fetch_assoc($liste_historique)): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: center">
                        <img src="../<?php echo fetchImageProgramme($historique['id_objectif']) ?>">
                    </td>
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle">
                        <span class="id_etat"><?php echo $historique['id_record'] ?></span>
                        <?php echo $historique['nom_programme'] ?>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle">
                        <span class="date_depart"><?php echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($historique['date_depart'])) ?></span>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle">
                        <span class="date_fin"><?php echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($historique['date_fin'])) ?></span>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle">
                        <span class="etat_programme"><?php echo $historique['etat_programme'] ?></span>
                        <?php echo echoEtatProgramme($historique['etat_programme']) ?>
                    </td>
                    <td style="vertical-align:middle">
                        <a class="uibutton icon add" href="#" style="width:160px;text-align: left">Créer un programme</a><br><a class="uibutton icon edit changer_etat" href="#" style="width:160px;text-align: left">Changer l'état</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endwhile; ?>`
```

And there is the form with the Id I want to fill

```
<div id="changer_etat" style="display:none" title="Changer l'état de mon programme">
        <table class="noborder" style="width:400px">
            <tr>
                <td style="width:200px;text-align: right;font-weight: bold">
                    Date de début :
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="date_debut" class="" id="date_depart">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:200px;text-align: right;font-weight: bold">
                    Date de fin :
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="date_fin" class="datepicker">
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td style="width:200px;text-align: right;font-weight: bold">
                    État :
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="etat" >
                        <option value="1">
                            En attente
                        </option>
                        <option value="2">
                            Commencé
                        </option>
                        <option value="3">
                            Terminé
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: thanks Nikita for editing

Comment: are you using any external library. `<input type="date_debut"/>` It needs to be `type="text"` ?

Comment: yes on me I do use an other library

Comment: did you try modifying it to `type="text"`?

Comment: yes sir, I've modified all by text, but it does not work. I've also tried in javascript directly  `document.getElementById('date_depart').value = date_depart` it does not work, I also did alert(date_depart); it return the good value.

Comment: its very odd, `.val()` or `.attr()` should eventually work. Could you reproduce this issue using jsfiddle.net?

Comment: this is here http://jsfiddle.net/PahK2/ you have to click on Historique de mes objectifs then on the column called ACTION on the text Changer l'état

Comment: I'm getting the alert with value "01-08-2013"..is it not working for you? which browser are you using?

Comment: chrome I also have the alert but it should filled the input with the value because we do that ` $('#date_depart').val(date_depart)` but it does not

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40276/discussion-between-krishna-and-user2506760)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set its attribute. Use `.val()`

```
$('#date_depart').val(date_depart)
```

EDIT:

The problem with the above DOM is that there are 2 input fields with the same ID. That makes the html invalid. You cannot have two elements wit the same ID.

Comment: that is what I do please have a look at my script in the beginning, but it does not work

Comment: @user2506760 what is `#date_depart`? An input field?

Comment: date_depart is the input id of the field I want to fill

Comment: @user2506760 - what does `console.log(date_depart)` give you?

Comment: it return to me that string '01-08-2013'

Comment: @user2506760 - can you post the HTML in your question?

Comment: @user2506760 - Found the issue. Your HTML has 2 instances of input fields with the same ID which is not allowed. All Ids need to be unique.